# Call a servlet method from a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I am currently developing a web application in J2ee with a servlet and jsp, when I try to call a method I created in my servlet from a jsp I get a 404 error The requested resource is not available.

The problem comes from the url I show you the parts of the code that cause problems.

```
@WebServlet("/BookServlet")

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     
    String action = request.getServletPath();
    switch(action) {
        case "/addBookForm":
                addBookForm(request, response);
                break;
        case "/addBook" :
                addBook(request, response);
                break;
        case "/updateBookForm" :
            updateBookForm(request, response);
            break;     
        case "/updateBook" :
            updateBook(request, response);
            break;
        case "/deleteBook" :
            deleteBook(request, response);
            break;
        case "/bookDetails" :
            bookDetails(request, response);
            break;
        default:
            listBook(request, response);
            break;
        }
         
}
```

The listBook method is well called.

In my jsp I put this

```
<a href="addBookForm" class="list-group-item">Ajouter un livre</a>
```

The problem is that when I click on add a book, the url is not good it gives me this : http://localhost:8080/Online_library/addBookForm

when normally it should give me http://localhost:8080/Online_library/BookServlet/addBookForm

And when I change this line @WebServlet("/BookServlet") in @WebServlet("/") the methods are called but I have another problem the images of my books are not displayed

Here is the line with the image :

```
<a href="bookDetails?idBook=<c:out value='${books.idBook}' />"><img src="${books.image}" style="width:100%; height:auto" class="img-thumbnail" ></a>
```

I think the problem comes from there @WebServlet but I'm not sure, if you have a little idea please share it

Comment: *And when I change this line @WebServlet("/BookServlet") in @WebServlet("/") the methods are called but I have another problem the images of my books are not displayed* - You haven't shown the code which displays an image.

Comment: Hi Arvind Kumar Avinash, I just added the line

Comment: I tried like this but now i don't see the image all, with @WebServlet("/BookServlet") and with @WebServlet("/")

Comment: Can you also mention the folder where you have stored the images?

Comment: All the images are stored in the folder "image" undeg webcontent

Comment: Did you try `src="images/${books.image}"`?

Comment: I tried but it's not working because I stored the url in the database : img/image1.jpg. I think the problem is not the images but the urls in the switch statement

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in jsp and servlets, but did you try to consider the full path of your servlet and it's resource in your jsp.
Where else the jsp should know about it, if not specified?

@WebServlet("/BookServlet")

```
<a href="BookServlet/addBookForm" class="list-group-item">Ajouter un livre</a>
```

Comment: Hi gson thank for your reply, I already tried like but it doesn't work :(